# Can I use the name of a character used by a video game for novel

Tags: copyright

I am writing a novel in which the name of one of my characters is "Captain Quick" I recently found out that this name had been used by a video game as "Captain Quick Mercury" so can I still use this name?
Note: I may publish this book in future.

Comment: I would check to see if the character's name is copyrighted. I would also check plagiarism laws but I can't see any issue with the naming of your character :)

Comment: @Charlie names cannot be copyrighted, they can be trademarks . There is no such thing as "plagiarism law" plagiarism may be academic misconduct but it's not illegal

Comment: So can I use it or not?

Comment: @AzizAgasi: Were you thinking of trying to find a publisher or self-publishing?